# Multiple Database Connections For One App

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Im a using this php mailing app and Im trying to have multiple databases under one folder without having to repeat this over and over. The db connection is using smarty template and im not quite sure how to go about this.

**Application files:** http://pommo-ext.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

**I'm trying to do this:**

```
If username/password is Smith => connect to DB_1 
If username/password is John => connect to DB_2 
If username/password is Jim => connect to DB_3
```

**This is my config.php file for the DB connector:**

http://pommo-ext.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/config.sample.php

```
[db_hostname] = localhost
[db_username] = root
[db_password] = root
[db_database] = db_1
[db_prefix] = db_
```

Also here is the class for the DB as well.
http://pommo-ext.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/inc/classes/pommo.php

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Pommo, but from your question I figure that you are trying to create some kind of multi-user environment with one installation of an application, but with different database settings. There's generally (for any application) no straight-forward or trivial way to do this.

First of all, you must rewrite all internal logic of Pommo to make sure that they use different database connections based on the username. The username, however, can't be stored in any database in that case, since the database must be selected based on the username. You could add another database for thsi information, but that's just silly.

Secondly, you want different databases, but I can't imagine why you'd want that. For starters, why not use table prefixes? Secondly, I'm sure that Pommo has some kind of multi-user environment, so that you can share the same installation with several users. Maybe that's not possible, but then you can do two things:

- Start looking for some other application.
- Start looking for some other enthausiast that already wrote what you want.

Finally, Smarty does not have to do anything with database connections. I imagine Pommo using Smarty for their templating or put Smarty templates in databases, but the actual database setup has to happen somewhere in PHP.

---

However, if you don't need some 'nice' solution, are prepared for serious ugliness and want a quick solution, you can probably use PHP sessions. You can store the username of the user in `$_SESSION['custom_username']` by requesting it on a login page. Note however that you must have a login page that comes before Pommo tries to verify the username that was passed in its database, since the database is dependend on the username. I'd suggest a separate page independent of your Pommo installation. Maybe you want to create something like a file that uses a GET parameter, sets the session and forwards to the application.

After that, in the config.php, you can check for the username in the session and change the properties based on that.

For this to work, you must set up your PHP sessions properly and if Pommo already uses sessions, you can probably reuse that functionality, but make sure that it does not interfere with Pommo's usage of it.

Comment: Yes im looking for a quick solution to be honest dont want to spend too much time on this. do you know of any example link on how to do this ?

Comment: I tried to explain how you'd generally modify any application to do what you want. It's not much more than programming a simple forwarding/login page and modifying your config.php. However, since it's not straight-forward, I don't think there are done-and-written tutorials for something like this. Are you really limited to doing this? Isn't there another solution that's much easier?

Comment: Yes creating a new login page is probably the best way to go about this but will the new login page bypass the pommo login page or will it just re-direct it to login again ?

Comment: If you want to bypass the Pommo login system, you have to feed into the login system somehow. You can't let Pommo decide whether the login was valid, since you have to redirect after that. You may create a central Pommo installation and use the username after verification to 'redirect' to the right Pommo by using the Pommo user data in your config.php. But that could get quite tricky, since you don't know in your config.php if the current Pommo user is that of the central Pommo or of the decentralized installation.